# SQL Check if coordinates are within radius of database coordinates

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, coordinates

I have a table containing smallInteger radius_size, varchar radius_lat and varchar radius_lng and I'm trying to make an Eloquent query where I can pass in a lat and lng value and get all records where the provided lat and lng fall into the record's radius from it's lat and lng, but the can't figure it out and the examples I find with similar cases or in other languages don't seem to help me.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Don't know eloquent, but you could simplify your problem if you were happy with a 2r x 2r square centred on your point, then you can simply use a 'between' statement of e.g. A.Lat between B.Lat-radius and B.lat+radius and A.Long between B.Long-radius and B.long+radius

Comment: @JeffUK, yeah I figured that would be the easiest solution, however our customers would not be pleased with that. :)

Comment: If you're displaying the results in e.g. google maps, a square or a rectangle might actually make more sense! Otherwise, time to brush up on the high school trigonometry everyone told you you'd never use in real life!